# Unexpected Characters after using \cal

Tags: symbols, mathcal

I am getting very strange compilation problems after using the `\cal` command in a very simple setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\Pp}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\Ee}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\Prob}{\text{P}}

\title{STAT 535 Homework 3}
\author{Sheridan Grant}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Theorem 2.2.8 and Proposition 2.2.9}

Here is normal stuff:
$n + b$

Now I'll try to do something with ``cal'':
$\cal{R}_n$

What?
$\cal{R}_n \sim \frac{n + b}{1}$

\end{document}
```

The result (compiled with `latexmk -pdf`) is:
[image: bizarre output with unexpected characters]

The problem is fixed if I switch to `{\cal R}_n` or `\mathcal{R}_n` but I don't understand why; I've been able to use `\cal` in the `\cal{R}` manner in the past without problems. I figure it might be nice to have an explanation easily available on here...

Comment: This is similar in nature to using `\bfseries{...}` - `\cal` *switches* the font, so everything following it will be changed. Using `\cal` within `$`...`$` provides a group, so it doesn't show with `$\cal R$`.

Comment: Dang sorry I didn't see the \cal{M}_n question when searching...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\cal` is a plain-TeX directive, and it works much like other plain-TeX directives such as `\rm`, `\bf`, `\it`, etc: It's a switch, i.e., it affects not just the next character but, instead, *all remaining material* in the current group. Writing `\cal{R}` is thus an accident waiting to happen, and in `\cal{R}_n \sim \frac{n + b}{1}` the accident is in full display. Write `{\cal R}_n ...` instead.

At any rate, in LaTeX documents you shouldn't use `\cal` to begin with. Use `\mathcal{...}` instead.